# How to implement Lists of Hashmap/ArrayList

Tags: java, list, maps, character, frequency

Hi everyone I am having a problem trying to get this to work. Basically what I wanted to do is to read a text file containing this kind of data not exactly but just similar and count the frequency of each letter appearing on each line. Also the real data contains any random ASCII from 0-255.

An examples is:

Hi this is john.
We are going .4%2) &,.! m@ll

What I wanted to have is something like this implemented in Lists of Maps

{H=3, i=3, ' '=3, t=1, h=2, s=2,... until the end of the line },

{W=1, e=2, ' '=4, a=1, r=1, g=2, o=1, i=1, n=1, .=2, 4=1, %=1.... until the end of line},

so its a Lists of Map

I have tried to research on similar questions but the closest I can do in coding it is this.

```
List <Map<String, Integer>> storeListsofMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
ArrayList <String> storePerLine = new ArrayList<String>();
String getBuf;

try {
FileReader rf = new FileReader("simpleTextCharDist.txt");
BufferedReader encapRF = new BufferedReader(rf);

getBuf = encapRF.readLine();

while (getBuf!=null){
storePerLine.add(getBuf);

getBuf = encapRF.readLine();
}

for (String index: storePerLine){
Map<String, Integer> storeCharAndCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Integer count = storeCharAndCount.get(index);
storeCharAndCount.put(index, (count==null)?count = 1:count+1);

storeListsofMaps.add(storeCharAndCount);
}

System.out.println("StoreListsofMaps: "+ storeListsofMaps);

encapRF.close();
}
```

I know this code would not execute the one I described but am stuck up until this part. The code I have shown will only count the word itself not each letter in the string. I tried counting iterating over each element in the string by converting the string into char [] and converting it back to string again, but it is very inefficient and produces alot of errors. Hope anyone would be kind enough to help.

Comment: Why don't you post a full class, with your code in the main method, and with types for all variables? That would make it easier to fix it.

Comment: Code formatting help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: This is the main code its just short because I just wanted to understand how to solve the problem. But apart from the code I posted the other lines are just declaration and catch expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pseudo algo to achieve this -

1. Using file I/O create a list containing 1 line as 1 element in the list
2. Write a small helper function which will:

   1. take String (representing an element from list created in step 1)
   2. iterate through the line
   3. create a map of char & count. This map should be the return type.
3. Create a `Map<String,Map<String,Int>>` where 1st String is the "Line1", "Line2", etc. 2nd String is the char value. The Map written inline is the map returned from Step 2.

This should work.

Comment: i did something similar but i'll try your solution again maybe it will work. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you are trying to do. Write down your algorithm in text form. Think about when you have to create your variables, aqnd which types your varibales need to have. Compare your written algorithm with your actual code.

Example algorithm:

1. Open file
2. Create a list of maps of charcaters to integers (ArrayList>)
3. Read all lines; for each line:

   1. Create a map char -> int for that line (HashMap)
   2. For each character c in the line:

      1. update the count in the map
   3. Store the map for one line in the list of maps